# Write the contra positive of the following statement.

Tags: real-analysis, logic

**Write the contra positive of the following statement.**

> Suppose $x\in \mathbb R$, and we know: for all $\epsilon \in \mathbb
>  R$, if $\epsilon>0,$ then $x\leq \epsilon$. Then $x \leq 0.$

The contrapositive of the statement is If $x>0$. Then there exists $\epsilon \in \mathbb R$ such that $x>\epsilon.$ is my contra positive statement is true?
Here
p: ($\forall \epsilon,(\epsilon>0 \implies x\leq \epsilon))$ and q:$x\leq 0$.
So , contapositive will be $\sim q\implies \sim p$
ie $\sim (x\leq 0)\implies \sim ((\forall \epsilon,(\epsilon>0 \implies x\leq \epsilon)$

ie $(x>0) \implies  ((\exists \epsilon,(\epsilon>0 \wedge \sim( x\leq \epsilon))$

$\therefore (x>0) \implies  ((\exists \epsilon,(\epsilon>0 \wedge ( x> \epsilon))$

Comment: p: ($\forall \epsilon,(\epsilon>0 \implies x\leq \epsilon))$ and q:$x\leq 0$. Right?

Comment: So , contapositive will be $\sim q\implies \sim p$

Comment: Am I correct?@RicardoCavalcanti

Comment: $(x>0) \implies  ((\exists \epsilon,(\epsilon>0 \wedge \sim( x\leq \epsilon))$ @RicardoCavalcanti

Comment: $(x>0) \implies  ((\exists \epsilon,(\epsilon>0 \wedge ( x> \epsilon))$

Comment: Is my contrapositive statement true now?@RicardoCavalcanti

Comment: By taking $\epsilon =x/3$ proof is complete. right?

Comment: Please do not delete questions after people have taken the time and effort to help with comments or answers. This is disrespectful and denies others with similar questions the benefits of those comments and answers.

Comment: sorry. Actually, It has no answer. i got the answer. That is why i did it. i won't repeat in the future.